# Zend Framework 2 routing with variables

Tags: php, zend-framework2

This might be a basic question but I've just recently started to use ZF2 and I' having a hard time working out the routing part...
The URL I'm trying to call is the following: http://localproject:8888/administrator/event/edit/9/event_test

My module.config file looks like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'administrator' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/administrator',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'MyModule\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'MyModule\Controller\User',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'event'=> array(
                    'type'    => 'literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/event',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\Event',
                            'action' => 'eventdashboard',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'edit' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/edit/:eventid/:name_technical',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'MyModule\Controller\Event',
                                    'action' => 'edit',
                                ),
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'eventid' => '\d'
                                )
                            ),
                            'may_terminate' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

But when I call the URL then I get a "Page not found." error message.

Controller, view files should be fine. The "New" form works fin with this URL: http://localproject:8888/administrator/event/add

The problem is when I try to include the event ID and technical name in the URL.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a page not found error from ZF2, or from Apache?

Comment: You should add `name_technical` under the key `constraints`.

Comment: @Tim Fountain: it is from ZF2

Comment: Code looks okay. Is the URL in your question the exact URL that's giving you the error? Does the 'edit' action exist in the controller? Is there any additional info in the error message?